# Oracle 12c - delete records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, sql-delete

I have a almost half a million records like below I need to delete:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID  LOG_DATE            DETAIL_LOG 
-----------  --------            ---------- 
00001        19/11/2018 12:03:37 Database user USER1; Department ID from '12345' to '';
00001        19/11/2018 12:03:37 Database user USER1; Department ID from '' to '12345';
00002        19/11/2018 12:02:06 Database user USER1; Department ID from '12345' to '';
00002        19/11/2018 12:02:07 Database user USER1; Department ID from '' to '12345';
00003        19/11/2018 07:22:10 Database user USER1; Department ID from '99999' to '';
00003        19/11/2018 07:22:11 Database user USER1; Department ID from '' to '99999';
00004        19/11/2018 09:40:11 Database user USER1; Department ID from '99999' to '';
00004        19/11/2018 09:40:12 Database user USER1; Department ID from '' to '22222';
```

I need to delete only these records which have the same `department id` in both records. So all of these need to be deleted except for `employee_id` `00004`. How can I do this?

Comment: ...it looks like you had a rogue update process that unset everything.  Shouldn't that mean that you want to _combine_ the records, in addition to removing the "no change" rows?  Presumably `00002` should be considered to have a blank department id, right (given the timestamps)?  Do you have any chains of multiple (more than two) records?  How about loops?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse This is a audit history table. There is a batch job that executes a package which updates a table column (`department id`) twice, once to `NULL` and then to a new value (derived from an xml data file); both times a trigger is fired that creates these audit logs. I have fixed the package so it doesn't update to null initially, so the trigger is called only once for each employee_id thus only one audit log record will be created.

Comment: How do you identify the start and end of a batch of update for an employee_id? For eg:- what if the employee_id `00004` got updated again 5 mins later and on what basis do you distinguish it whether the updates belong to this group or another group?

Comment: @KaushikNayak I'm not sure if that's possible to distinguish.

Comment: Well, then  a crucial bit of information is missing isn't it,to arrive at a logic to delete specific rows, given your dataset? We could help you if you tell us any other metric which may allow us to group them accurately to prepare for deletion. Deciding that on a pattern of just  a few random set of sequences won't be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table mytab(eid varchar2(5), logdate date, log varchar2(200));

insert into mytab values('00001',to_date('19/11/2018 12:03:37','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'Database user USER1; Department ID from ''12345'' to '''';');
insert into mytab values('00001',to_date('19/11/2018 12:03:37','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'Database user USER1; Department ID from '''' to ''12345'';');
insert into mytab values('00002',to_date('19/11/2018 12:02:06','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'Database user USER1; Department ID from ''12345'' to '''';');
insert into mytab values('00002',to_date('19/11/2018 12:02:07','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'Database user USER1; Department ID from '''' to ''12345'';');
insert into mytab values('00003',to_date('19/11/2018 07:22:10','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'Database user USER1; Department ID from ''99999'' to '''';');
insert into mytab values('00003',to_date('19/11/2018 07:22:11','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'Database user USER1; Department ID from '''' to ''99999'';');
insert into mytab values('00004',to_date('19/11/2018 09:40:11','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'Database user USER1; Department ID from ''99999'' to '''';');
insert into mytab values('00004',to_date('19/11/2018 09:40:12','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'Database user USER1; Department ID from '''' to ''22222'';');

commit;

select * from mytab;
```

**Output:**

```
EID     LOGDATE     LOG
00001   19-NOV-18   Database user USER1; Department ID from '12345' to '';
00001   19-NOV-18   Database user USER1; Department ID from '' to '12345';
00002   19-NOV-18   Database user USER1; Department ID from '12345' to '';
00002   19-NOV-18   Database user USER1; Department ID from '' to '12345';
00003   19-NOV-18   Database user USER1; Department ID from '99999' to '';
00003   19-NOV-18   Database user USER1; Department ID from '' to '99999';
00004   19-NOV-18   Database user USER1; Department ID from '99999' to '';
00004   19-NOV-18   Database user USER1; Department ID from '' to '22222';
```

**Solution:**

```
delete from mytab 
 where eid in (
        select eid 
          from (
                select x.eid, max(x.from_dept) max_from_dept, max(x.to_dept) max_to_dept 
                  from (
                        select eid, 
                               rtrim(ltrim(regexp_substr(log,'(from)[^(to)]+(to)'),'from '),' to') from_dept,
                               rtrim(ltrim(regexp_substr(log,'(to)[^(;)]+(;)'),'to '),';') to_dept
                          from mytab) x 
              group by x.eid) y 
         where y.max_from_dept = y.max_to_dept);

commit;

select * from mytab;
```

**Output:**

```
EID     LOGDATE     LOG
00004   19-NOV-18   Database user USER1; Department ID from '99999' to '';
00004   19-NOV-18   Database user USER1; Department ID from '' to '22222';
```